# GLOB recursion issue

Tags: python, recursion, glob

Hi I need to recursively get all files and subdirectories in a directory when I add the code to get the md5 hashes glob stops being recursive

```
 def get_original_dir(target_dir):
     dirs = ['File,Md5!']
     files = glob.iglob(target_dir + '/**/*.*',
                   recursive=True)
     for file in files:
         with open(file, "rb") as f:
             file_hash = hashlib.md5()
             while chunk := f.read(8192):
                 file_hash.update(chunk)
         dirs.append(file + ',' + str(file_hash.hexdigest() + '!'))
         return dirs
```

code will run but it wont work recursively not sure why thanks!

Comment: The fault is not `glob.glob`.  The fault is the `return` statement you have that exits after processing one file.  I assume you want that out-indented by one.

Comment: You might consider replacing this entire thing with a single shell command: `find $TARGET_DIR -type f | md5sum`.